# Spring - RestTemplate Error calling a https rest service (Certificate error)

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl, ssl-certificate

I call in tomcat war a rest web service. I do the web service invocation with this:

```
    public UsuarioDTO validarDatosToken(String token, boolean incluirRoles) throws ModeloException, DAOException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        UserRestVO page = restTemplate.getForObject("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), UserRestVO.class);

        if (page != null && page.getStatusResult() != null && page.getStatusResult().getStatusCode().equals("OK") && page.getUser() != null) {
            ------------
            return datos;
        } else {
            throw new ModeloException(ErroresGeneralesEnum.ERROR_TOKEN_CADUCADO);
        }
    }
}


public Authentication authenticateReal(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    UsuarioDTO usuario = null;
    try {
        usuario = usuariosService.validarDatosToken(username, true);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class.getName()).error(e);

        throw new BadCredentialsException("Username not found.");
    }



}
```

The following error is produced when web service is called. I try to do a lot of things but notting works:

I think that the problem is with the certificate but i dont solve it.
¿Do you have any idea?

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx":java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); nested exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:512)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:243)
>       at custom.service.usuarios.impl.UsuariosServiceImpl.validarDatosToken(UsuariosServiceImpl.java:69)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.validarDatosToken(Unknown Source)
>       at custom.view.filter.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticateReal(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:48)
>       at custom.view.filter.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:37)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
>       at custom.view.filter.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
>       at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
>       at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:409)
>       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:275)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
>       at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:551)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
>       at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
>       at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
>       at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
>       at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:528)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.(SSLContextImpl.java:495)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1240)
>       ... 64 more

Comment: mine exception was **org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for 
"https://web-service-url"** and after checking dynamically URL was wrongly called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your code i dont see any specific SSL configuration for your RestTemplate. Since i dont know which version of Spring (and related HTTPClient), i suggest try starting with the following code and see what happens:

```
public void tryme() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
 String urlOverHttps = "https:xxxxxxx";  
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
      HttpClients.custom()
             .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
             .build();
   HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory reqFactory = 
              new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
   reqFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

   ResponseEntity<String> response =  
          new RestTemplate(reqFactory).exchange(
                  urlOverHttps, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
   String responseCode = response.getStatusCode();
}
```

This should in theory bypass certs check. It requires HTTPClient 4.4. As i said, you dont expose many details of your current configuration so i can really only wild guess here.

Comment: I do thar buy i obtain de same error: errores.ModeloException: I/O error on GET request for "https://xxxxxxx":java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext); nested exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Comment: The last error that the full stack write is the following: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:709)
 at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
 at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:221)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultTrustManager(SSLContextImpl.java:528)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>

Answer (score 1):

I found the error
Somebody change the etc/init.d/tomcat7 to include  two lines with a invalid cert store. Removing it, it's work! thanks to all

-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456