# Getting Exception with message "http protocol is not supported" when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to hit a URL using GET request using RestTemplate. It is giving an exception stating http protocol is not supported.

I'm able to get the expected response using plain old HttpURLConnection method to hit the endpoint. But I'm unable to do so using the rest template.
I'm not using any kind of VPN or proxy while trying this out.

Following is the code I'm using. I'll be replacing the actual ip and port used with ip:port.

```
final String url = "http://ip:port/h2h.php?channelid=acrs&posid=1";
final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
final HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("", httpHeaders)
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Exception Trace

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://ip:port/h2h.php": http protocol is not supported; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: http protocol is not supported
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:673) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:538) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$aa4e9ed0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.captureUrlTemplate(RestTemplateUrlTemplateCapturingAspect.java:33) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8fab6610.exchange(<generated>) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.gdn.x.pulsa.service.impl.TransactionServiceImpl.getTransactionResult(MobileTransactionServiceImpl.java:118) ~[classes/:na]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: Code with HttpUrlConnection

```
try {
      URL obj = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
      con.setRequestMethod("GET");
      con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
      String inputLine;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
      }
      in.close();
      System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Try what is mentioned in this answer:
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921592/11839229](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921592/11839229)

Answer (score 0):

```
try using a closebale httpclient 
   CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory
            = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    ResponseEntity<String> response
            = new RestTemplate(requestFactory).exchange(
            url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: Hi @Manoj. Updated the code to use hostname verifier to my ClosableHttpClient. Remaining code was already in place. Still getting the same error on hitting the endpoint. :(

Comment: please try with https it should be work might be and  please add the code for HttpURLConnection

Comment: I get "I/O error on GET request for "https://ip:port/h2h.php": Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?" when I try using https. I've updated the HttpUrlConnection code in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use `RestTemplate`:

```
String payload = "something";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.postForObject(url, new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers), String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpClientBuilder`.

That way you can set `enableHttp` by calling `setEnableHttp(true)` like so:

```
HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
httpClientBuilder.setConnectionTimeout(30);
httpClientBuilder.setSocketTimeout(30);
httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnTotal(20);
httpClientBuilder.setMaxConnPerRoute(2);
httpClientBuilder.setEnableHttp(true); // <- this will fix it

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
    httpClientBuilder.newHttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()
);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

String response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
    "http://ip:port/h2h.php?channelid=acrs&posid=1",
    String.class,
    new HttpEntity<>(headers))
.getBody();
```